# Using %dopar% with a custom function

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

So I've got this function meant to group measurements from multiple probes that fall into defined regions.

```
HMkit.dmr<-function(Mat,Classes,method.fdr=c("BH","bonferroni"),probe.features) {

   #Annotate first...
   require(plyr)
   require(dplyr)


   #Filter matrix for testing and stuff...

   message("Setting up merged table")
   Mat2<-Mat[match(probe.features$probe,rownames(Mat)),]

   #Split by classes

   if(!is.factor(Classes)) {
       Classes<-as.factor(Classes)
   }
   Class.1<-levels(Classes)[[1]]
   Class.2<-levels(Classes)[[2]]

   C1.Mat<-Mat2[,Classes==Class.1]
   C2.Mat<-Mat2[,Classes==Class.2]

   #Summarise and run wilcoxon's test for each dmr...
   num.regions<-length(unique(as.character(probe.features$region.id)))
   pvals.vec<-numeric(length=num.regions)
   unique.regions<-unique(as.character(probe.features$region.id))
   message(num.regions)
   Meds.1<-numeric(length=num.regions);Meds.2<-numeric(length=num.regions)

   for (i in 1:num.regions) {
       region<-probe.features%>%filter(region.id %in% unique.regions[[i]])
       Set1.Mat<-as.numeric(C1.Mat[rownames(C1.Mat) %in% region$probe,])
       Set2.Mat<-as.numeric(C2.Mat[rownames(C2.Mat) %in% region$probe,])
       pvals.vec[[i]]<-wilcox.test(Set1.Mat,Set2.Mat)$p.value
       Meds.1[[i]]<-median(Set1.Mat)
       Meds.2[[i]]<-median(Set2.Mat)
       message(i)
   }

    #Output frame
    dmrs.frame<-data.frame(region=unique.regions,pval=pvals.vec,G1=Meds.1,G2=Meds.2,dB=Meds.1-Meds.2)
    dmrs.frame$q.val<-p.adjust(dmrs.frame$pval,method=method.fdr)
    groups.ids<-levels(Classes)
    return(list(dmrs=dmrs.frame,groups=groups.ids))
}
```

The code basically splits a matrix into two groups by samples and then pulls in the values of all probes that are defined as being in a region, calls a wilcox.test and a median summarisation step and uses it to populate vectors created beforehand.

I have tried to replace the for in the for loop with doparallel function in the foreach package but have not been able to get it to populate the vector with the correct outcomes. I want to know how to correctly use parallelisation with the function above - either by modifying the for loop, or by modifying the function call so regions are broken down into chunks that are processed in parallel.

Example objects follow below...

```
Mat<-matrix(runif(200,0,1), ncol=10,nrow=20)
rownames(Mat)<-paste0("p",1:20)
colnames(Mat)<-paste0("S",1:10)

Classes<-as.character(c(rep("G1",6),rep("G2",4)))
probe.features<-data.frame(probe=paste0("p",1:20),region.id=c(rep("R1",5),rep("R2",3),rep("R3",4),rep("R5",4),rep("R6",4))
```

and the function is run using

```
x<-HMkit.dmr(Mat,Classes,method.fdr=c("BH"),probe.features=probe.features)
```

In practise, there are 30,000 regions I am looking at, and want to parallelise the function across multiple cores on windows because serial execution can take up to 40 minutes. How do I do this?

Addendum - I tried to do this with

```
 library(doParallel)
 ncores<-2
 Cl<-makeCluster(2)
 registerDoParallel(Cl)
x<-foreach(i=1:length(unique(probe.features$region.id)),packages=c("plyr","dplyr"))%dopar%HMkit.dmr(Mat,Classes,probe.features=probe.features,method.fdr="BH")
```

However, doing that just returned two copies of the same results as the serial function, what I want it to do is break down regions in probe.features$region.id into chunks that go to different cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that your "for" loop can be easily parallelized. It's just building up three vectors, one element per iteration, where each vector will become a column of "dmrs.frame". So each iteration is computing one row of the result.

To use "foreach", you can simply concatenate those three values into a vector. The `.combine` option is used to combine all of those the vectors into a matrix with "rbind":

```
m <- foreach(uregion=unique.regions, .combine='rbind',
             .packages=c('plyr', 'dplyr')) %dopar% {
    region<-probe.features%>%filter(region.id %in% uregion)
    Set1.Mat<-as.numeric(C1.Mat[rownames(C1.Mat) %in% region$probe,])
    Set2.Mat<-as.numeric(C2.Mat[rownames(C2.Mat) %in% region$probe,])
    c(wilcox.test(Set1.Mat, Set2.Mat)$p.value,
      median(Set1.Mat), median(Set2.Mat))
}
```

I got rid of the "i" variable since I think it's more readable to simply iterate over the elements of "unique.regions".

Now you can create "dmrs.frame" using the columns of matrix "m":

```
dmrs.frame <- data.frame(region=unique.regions,
        pval=m[,1] G1=m[,2] G2=m[,3], dB=m[,2]-m[,3])
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, works excellently - although the subscripts in dmrs.frame<-data.frame(...) need swapping to indicate columns instead of rows.

Comment: @AnkurChakravarthy Thanks for pointing that out. It should be fixed in my answer now.